# Manipulate legend values and increments in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to manipulate the legend in my chart. This script:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=year, y=theme, size=count)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c('EG','DS','BB','KB','FB','SH','LS','NW','GB',
                            'WH','MC','VM','NB','SB','CS','LP','KS','BS','AB')) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2016),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,
                                              1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,
                                              2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.title.y =element_text(size=15), 
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=15)) +
  xlab(" ") + ylab("Theme")
```

produces this chart:

[image]

The legend is generated with the values 5, 10 and 15. I need to include the value 1 in the legend such that it includes the values 1, 5, 10 and 15. I have been trying out various `theme`commands without luck.

Any suggestions?

Here's my data frame:

```
structure(list(year = c(2015, 2014, 2012, 2003, 1991, 1987, 1977, 
1975, 1968, 1965, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 
2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 
1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1985, 1983, 1982, 1980, 
1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 
2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 
1998, 1997, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1987, 1986, 1985, 
1984, 1983, 1981, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1964, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 
2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1996, 1995, 1994, 
1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1983, 1980, 1979, 1978, 
1976, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1967, 1965, 1962, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2000, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1991, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1980, 
1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 
2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2000, 1999, 1998, 
1997, 1996, 1995, 1991, 1990, 1983, 1979, 1976, 2016, 2015, 2014, 
2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2002, 
2001, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 
1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1980, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 
2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 
2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1988, 1986, 1985, 1984, 
1983, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 
2008, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 
1994, 1991, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1978, 1977, 1975, 1973, 1968, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2009, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 1999, 1998, 
1997, 1995, 1993, 1992, 1987, 1985, 1979, 1965, 1964, 2015, 2014, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 
2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1992, 1991, 1990, 
1988, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1976, 
1975, 1974, 1973, 1968, 1967, 1963, 1961, 2016, 2015, 2012, 2009, 
2004, 2002, 2001, 1999, 1998, 1993, 1992, 1990, 1987, 1985, 1979, 
1965, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 
2004, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1988, 
1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1976, 1975, 1973, 1968, 1961, 2016, 2015, 
2014, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 
2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 
1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1980, 1979, 1977, 1976, 
1975, 1973, 1968, 1961, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 
2008, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2000, 1998, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1988, 
1986, 1983, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 
2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 
2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 
1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1983, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1973, 
1972, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2002, 2000, 1999, 1998, 
1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1989, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1978, 
1976, 1975, 1973, 1969, 1968, 1967, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 
1996, 1995, 1994, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1984, 1983, 1975, 
1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 
2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 
1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 
1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1973, 
1972, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 2016), theme = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("ALL", "AB", "BB", "BS", 
"CS", "DS", "EG", "FB", "GB", "KB", "KS", "LS", "LP", "MC", "NB", 
"NW", "SB", "SH", "VM", "WH"), class = "factor"), count = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 7, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 12, 4, 5, 11, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 10, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
6, 9, 6, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 
2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 12, 1, 11, 11, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 8, 4, 
1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 
7, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 14, 7, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10, 14, 6, 11, 6, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 
3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6, 4, 9, 3, 10, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 5, 12, 6, 9, 15, 9, 13, 7, 10, 7, 8, 
2, 8, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 6, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 11)), .Names = c("year", 
"theme", "count"), row.names = 58:654, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 15))`.